# Странное поведение dict.fromkeys (python)

Tags: python, словари

Словарь который я создал при помощи `dict.fromkeys` работает не правильно, а словарь который я создал использовав `{}` работает верно. Причем эти два словаря одинаковые, исходя из `d == d2`.
В чем может быть проблема? Может это баг?
Тестировал на версии Python 3.8.6

```
d = dict.fromkeys(['3', '5', '4', '7'], [])
d2 = {'3': [], '5': [], '4': [], '7': []}
print(d)
print(d2)
print(d==d2) # True

d['3'].append('Сергей')
d2['3'].append('Сергей')
print(d)
print(d2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: их документации: `All of the values refer to just a single instance, so it generally doesn’t make sense for value to be a mutable object such as an empty list. To get distinct values, use a dict comprehension instead.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда вы передали список (`[]`) методу `dict.fromkeys()`, он создал новый словарь, но каждому ключу этого словаря соответствует *один и тот же* список, который вы ему передали. А во втором случае вы создаёте такой же словарь, но в нём каждому ключу соответствуют *разные* списки. Доказательство:

Код:

```py
d = dict.fromkeys(['3', '5', '4', '7'], [])
d2 = {'3': [], '5': [], '4': [], '7': []}

print('d:')
for v in d.values():  # Выводим ID значений словаря `d`
    print(id(v))

print('d2:')
for v in d2.values():  # То же самое для `d2`
    print(id(v))
```

Вывод:

```
d:
1804055070080  # (1)
1804055070080
1804055070080
1804055070080
d2:
1804054355584  # (2)
1804057678080
1804054325824
1804054726272
```

1. *Все* ID - одинаковые (это значит, что в значениях словаря `d` содержаться ссылки на один и тот же список);
2. Здесь ID разные - значит, здесь содержаться разные списки.

PS: у вас числа в выводе будут другие.

Comment: Спасибо за ясный ответ, теперь встало все на свои места!

Comment: @User5784, пожалуйста )) Рад был помоч